# POST request authorisation header

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, mailchimp

I'm having some issues with sending a POST request to subscribe users to a MailChimp list. This is what I've got so far:

```
    NSString *Post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{email_address:%@, status:pending}",email];
    NSData *PostData = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/124709/members/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req addValue:@"apikey:*****************" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorisation"];
    [req addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];
    [req setHTTPBody:PostData];

    NSData *res = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:res encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

but every single time I get a response saying "Your request did not include an API key.". I've obviously hidden my key but it's definitely a valid one, so that can't be the problem. I'm following the following curl request code:

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/57afe96172/members' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"email_address":"urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", "status":"subscribed"}' \
--include
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: the link contains a file what are u trying to do with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This, I have done it like this

```
[request setValue@"apikey:*****************" forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorisation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *Post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{email_address:%@, status:pending}",email];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/124709/members/"];    

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod:"POST"];
    [request setValue:"YOUR_KEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorisation"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
              if (responseObject)
              {                        
              }
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
               }];
              [op start];
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but I think you misspelled `Authorization`. Also it should be `Content-Type`.